# Is there a way to dynamically set the default value of a wtform radiofield from within the html template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm trying to dynamically set the value of a radio field within the HTML template but I'm not sure how to set the default selection. I want to do this because the forms I want to use are forms that can be saved and re-edited if need be, so I want the default values to be values set when previously saved/submitted.

the wtform fields

```py
field_1 = StringField('field_1')
radio_1 = RadioField('radio_1', choices=[(1,'Yes'),(2,'No')])
```

what i want to be able to do is something like this:

data is database data

```
{% if data.field_1 = 'X' %}
    {{ form.radio_1(id="radio_1",class="ff-style-radio",default=1) }}
{% else %}
    {{ form.radio_1(id="radio_1",class="ff-style-radio",default=2) }} 
{% endif %}
```

I haven't had any success trying this method, swapping default for value, etc. Is something like this possible? If not how would I separate the wtform radio field choices so I can just manually mark which selection is checked? Or should I just use the base HTML method and do something like this:

```
<ul class="ff-style-radio" id="radio_1">
    <li>
        {% if data.field_1 = 'X' %}
            <input id="radio_1-0" name="radio_1" type="radio" value="Yes" checked> 
        {% else %}
            <input id="radio_1-0" name="radio_1" type="radio" value="Yes"> 
        {% endif %}        
        <label for="radio_1-0">Yes</label>
   </li>
    <li>
        {% if data.field_1 = 'X' %}
            <input id="radio_1-1" name="radio_1" type="radio" value="No"> 
        {% else %}
            <input id="radio_1-1" name="radio_1" type="radio" value="No" checked> 
        {% endif %} 
        <label for="radio_1-1">No</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the form to edit data already in your database, you should supply this data to the form at creation time in your view function. This will allow you to keep your templates simple and reusable. Data from the database can be passed to the form either as an object or as a dictionary https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forms.html. If your form maps directly to a database table you can just pass this unmodified from your query. In the following code I've followed your example and created a new dictionary to set the value of `radio_1` based on the value of `field_1`.

```
@app.route("/myurl")
def myview():
    # do database lookup here
    olddata = {"radio_1": 1 if data.field_1 == "X" else 2}
    form = Myform(formdata=request.form, data=olddata)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        # .....
```